# Turn off or on any services dynamically from outside of Program.cs for Blazor 8

Tags: c#

During I am watching one Udemy video, I had had one question How I can set any parameter's argument from outside Program.cs or turning off or on any services or adding or removing any services from outside it.

Here is the example one I was watching. This is for the authentication's setting on custom policy.

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MyCookieAuth").AddCookie("MyCookieAuth", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieAuth";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Admin"));
    options.AddPolicy("MustBelongToHRDepartment", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Department", "HR"));
    options.AddPolicy("HRManagerOnly", policy => policy
        .RequireClaim("Department", "HR")
        .RequireClaim("Manager")
        .Requirements.Add(new HRManagerProbationRequirement(3)));
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HRManagerProbationRequirementHandler>();
```

Here is my part code for Authentication setting.

I am looking for how I can set int 3 from outside of Program.cs.

```cs
HRManagerProbationRequirement(3)
```

Because I want to make the Admin user to change it on the Admin Setting Razor page. This is one of mine How I can treat any services from outside of Program.cs
(turn off, turn on, set any parameter's aurguments, register or removing)

Below is HRManagerProbationRequirement service code.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace WebApp_UnderTheHood.Authorization
{
    public class HRManagerProbationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public HRManagerProbationRequirement(int probationMonths)
        {
            ProbationMonths = probationMonths;
        }

        public int ProbationMonths { get; }
    }

    public class HRManagerProbationRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HRManagerProbationRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HRManagerProbationRequirement requirement)
        {
            if (!context.User.HasClaim( x => x.Type == "EmploymentDate"))
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(context.User.FindFirst(x => x.Type == "EmploymentDate")?.Value, out DateTime employmentDate))
            {
                var period = DateTime.Now - employmentDate;
                if (period.Days > 30 * requirement.ProbationMonths)
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;            
        }
    }
}
```